# Access Denied with DbContext(DbConnection, bool)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to initialize a `DbContext` using the constructor `DbContext(DbConnection,bool)` but an exception is thrown.

I'm using MySQL v5.7.9, Connector/Net 6.9.8.

To clarify, I am successfully able to connect and query the database using `MySqlCommand`.

```
        using (var connection = Database.Connect())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM `database`.`table`";
                command.Prepare();

                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    List<StateObject> items = new List<object>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        incidents.Add(new StateObject(reader));
                    }
                    Items = new ObservableCollection<StateObject>(items);
                }
            }
        }
```

Exception:

```
System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'floortracker'@'localhost' (using password: NO) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'floortracker'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

From what I can see, it looks like despite my passing a DbConnection object, DbContext is building a brand new connection anyway, and guessing only portions of the connection string.

Am I using this constructor wrong?

DbContext

```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class IncidentContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IncidentModel> Incidents { get; set; }

        public IncidentContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
            : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
        {

        }
    }
```

Incident

```
    [Table("incidents")]
    public class IncidentModel : ModelBase
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("incId")]
        public int IncidentID { get; set; }
    }
```

Used like so:

```
        public void GetIncident()
        {
                using (var context = new IncidentContext(Database.GetConnection(), true))
                {
                    var completeIncident = context.Incidents.FirstOrDefault(incident => incident.IncidentID == Current.IncidentID);
                }
        }
```

Database static class

```
public static MySqlConnection Connect()
{
    try
    {
        var c = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=username;pwd=password;database=database;port=3306;");
        c.Open();
        return c;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exception said, your user is not authorized to connect to the database, change your connection string ( user and pwd) and check that this user has access to do crud in your db

Comment: My connection string has a password. The exception states that no password was used. The connection string in my App.config also has a password. I don't know where the connection string is coming from. As a test, I removed the connection string from App.config and the error persists.

Comment: @user2210050 perhaps because the user you're using can access it locally but not remotely and you're trying to access it from a machine that is not the one running the database? Then u would have to add the permissions to your database.

Comment: @Prix I am able to SELECT using the given connection string, and I am able to use `DbContext(connectionString)` and retrieve records using EF.